# Share button on collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have seen examples on adding a share button but these have the need to input the filename to be shared for example: `[controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialsharing-facebook-image.jpg"]];`, how could this be achieved when using different items from a collection view?

Answer (score 0):

> -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>       UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"sampleCell"
>   forIndexPath:indexPath];
>
> ```
> UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
> [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialsharing-facebook-image.jpg"]
> ```
>
> forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>       btn.tag = indexPath.row;
>       [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>
> [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
>   return cell; }

You can access particular button via its tag...